# ListViewAnimations only works when the Listview has only 1 view/element

Tags: android, listview, animation

I am using [ListViewAnimations](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations) I am having this weird problem, 
the animation is skipped and all of the views are populated if the list contains more than 1 element, but animation works if there is only one element to populate.

```
class AdapterOutcome extends CursorAdapter {



public AdapterOutcome(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
    super(context, c, 0);
}



@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {


    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.outcome_custom_row, parent, false);

}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    //finding the Views
    TextView amonut = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.amount);
    ImageView transactionType = (ImageView)     view.findViewById(R.id.custom_row_icon);
    TextView time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.timeid);
    TextView location = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.location);
    TextView date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
    TextView type_icon = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.type_icon);


    //Creating Cursors for each View
    String cursorTranscationType = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_transactionType"));
    String cursorAmount = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_amount"));
    String cursorTime = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_time"));
    String cursorLocation = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_location"));
    String cursorDay = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_day"));
    String cursorMonth = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_month"));
    String cursorYear = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_year"));

    DateFormat dateformat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);
   // Date myDate = new Date(Integer.parseInt(cursorYear)-1900,     Integer.parseInt(cursorMonth)-1, Integer.parseInt(cursorDay));

    //set the data from the Cursor to the Views
    amonut.setText(String.valueOf("- " + cursorAmount));
    time.setText(String.valueOf(cursorTime));
    location.setText(String.valueOf(cursorLocation));
   // date.setText( dateformat.format(myDate));






    if (cursorTranscationType.equals("Purchase")) {
        type_icon.setText("P");


    }
    else{
        type_icon.setText("C");


        }

    }


}
```

Comment: This project hasn't been updated in 2 years. Perhaps you should consider using `RecyclerView` instead, which has better APIs for animating items and is intended to be a replacement for `ListView` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use a custom adapter for your list view? if yes, save the last position of your getView in a global int variable and when next a view need to be populated, use the last position.
if this is not clear enough, post a sample of your code.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Animating a view can only work on the Override getView method. example for animation on getView                   Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context of the activity that calls the adapter, (position > lastPosition) ? R.anim.up : R.anim.down);
convertView.startAnimation(animation);
 lastPosition =  position;//save last position;

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Animating a view can only work on the Override getView method. example for animation on getView                   @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {                                                                                                 Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context of the activity that calls the adapter, (position > lastPosition) ? R.anim.up : R.anim.down);
convertView.startAnimation(animation);
 lastPosition =  position;//save last position;    }

Comment: lastPostition is a glolbal int = -1;  on your res, create a forlder called anim and paste the following code for up.xml                                                                           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="100%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="300" />
</set>

Comment: while this for down.xml                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="-100%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="400" />
</set>

Comment: ok so the animation now work I just put the adapter in the getView method but now whenever I interact with activity the animation start to render the again, if I scroll up or down, swipe left or right to navigate between the activities the animation restart